# Jquery selector variable syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery

This should be a simple issue, I can't make it work however. The code takes a sentence `line_2` and animates each letter `line_2[i]`, I want to add a color to each letter. I added a variable heya and used a selector as shown in the code but its not working. Im probably something simple.

Here is the code:

```
for (i = line_2.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    $('<div>', {
        var heya = "line2" + i;
        html: '<br><br><br><br>' + '<div id= ' + heya + '>' + line_2[i] + '</div>'
    })
    $("#" + heya).css("color", "blue");
    .addClass('letter')
        .appendTo(elements);
}
```

Comment: There is a semicolon after "blue" that prob shouldn't be there.

Comment: I don't think you can effect the css for an element until it has been added to the dom.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what's going on inside that `$('<div>', { .... })` code. That looks pretty wrong too.

Comment: Just a general hint that probably will save a lot of time for you : you should use the developer console that's provided by your browser. It shows most of the issues you got with your code. (IIRC in IE,Firefox and Chrome it's enabled with F12 or F11(IE?), or using the menu, in Safari it's Cmd+Alt+C). Also try getting used to the javascript debugger that's also included in most browsers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something more like this may do the trick:

```
for (i = line_2.length-1; i >=0; i--) 
{
    var heya ="line2" + i;

    $('<div></div>', {
        html: '<br><br><br><br>' + '<div id=\"' + heya +'\">' + line_2.charAt(i) + '</div>'
    })
    .css("color","blue")
    .addClass('letter')
    .appendTo(elements);
}
```

And to be clear, with the `i--` in the `for` loop you are going through the string from end to beginning rather than beginning to end.

Comment: 1980 thanks! you saved me lots of time. Using your code, the div with heya id is actually useless. is having a <div></div>, in the selector the same as selecting the dom element by id? About the counter, yes its intentional, I created a jquery animation and it needed to go from right to left!

Comment: If you want to select a div, it would be `$('div')`. The syntax we're using here is creating a new div on the fly. The new div is returned then we apply the css and class to it then append it to an actual element. Prior to the append it just exists in memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few syntax errors and statements in the wrong place

`var heya ="line2" + i;` needs to be outside the `{}` otherwise you are going to get an error from it being in there

You probably want:

```
var heya ="line2" + i;
$('<div>', {
    html: '<br><br><br><br>' + '<div id="' + heya +'">' + line_2[i] + '</div>'
});
```

Also since your element hasnt been added to the dom yet you cannot use a `jQuery(selector)` to select it yet, you have to provide jQuery a context on which to search on

```
var ele = $('<div>', {
   html: '<br><br><br><br>' + '<div id="' + heya +'">' + line_2[i] + '</div>'
});
jQuery("#"+heya,ele).css("color","blue")
.addClass('letter')
.appendTo(elements);
```

But I do not see why you are creating a wrapping div since you are just using the inner one, you can simplify it with:

```
$('<div>', {
   id:"line2" + i,
   html: line_2[i]
}).css("color","blue")
.addClass('letter')
.appendTo(elements);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that do not generate any errors (based on your original code):

```
for (i = line_2.length-1; i >=0; i--) {
    var heya = "line2" + i;
    $('<div>', {
        html: '<br><br><br><br>' + '<div id= ' + heya +'>' + line_2[i] + '</div>'
    });

    $("#" + heya).css("color","blue")
        .addClass('letter')
        .appendTo(elements);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code removes the sentence and replaces it with colored text:

```
<span id="line_2">Lazy</span>

function execute() {
    var line2 = $('#line_2');
    var colors = ['blue','red','green','gray'];
    var txt = line2.text();
    line2.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
        line2.append('<span style="color: ' + colors[i] + '">' + txt[i] + '</span>');
    }
}
execute();
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y7rv81rh/)